# How to access full view counts

Tags: support, views

The recent update to the question view counter means that, when I want to check the impact of some of my more viewed questions, instead of seeing the useful number `2309`, I see `2k`, which can mean anything from `1500` to `2499`. Not that useful.

Is there any way at all now to view the full view count of a question?

Comment: Hover. I'm guessing you mean 2499 

Comment: Which site?  If I hover the mouse (on my desktop) over the "viewed 2k times" it says "Viewed 2,198 times".

Comment: For 2536 views it shows 3k views, we may need to display views with one fraction point such as 2.5k, I am referring to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54758872/spring-boot-security-postman-gives-401-unauthorized

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to **know how many views the question has**, in most browsers you can just hover the views counter with the cursor and it will display the actual number.

Otherwise you could right click on the view counter and inspect the html element on the page.

Here's an example using Google Chrome browser, from the [StackOverflow most popular post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array):

[image]

And check the attribute `title`:

[image]

Comment: In most browsers html elements with "title" attributes display their title when the user hovers over the element. It's probably considerably less steps for most people to just hover over the view count with their mouse.